# Flex Builder 4 cant run or debug

Tags: flash, debugging, builder

I've been working in Flash BUilder 4.0. I installed Flash Builder 4.5, and switched to the workspace I had used for 4.0.  Then we were told to go back to 4.0, and now I can't run or debug.  I can build, but then I have to double click on the .html file to run.  Right clicking doesn't bring up run or debug, and the run and debug icons are not in my toolbar.  Any ideas?  I thought I would check if it is something simple before I reinstall.

Comment: I don't have flash builder here just flex but it seems to me like the project settings are not back words compatible. I would try and load it up in 4.5 and do an export of the project. then load up 4.0 and do an import. But not sure you can do that in flash builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a full backup of your workspace first so you can always go back to the previous situation!**

Try removing the hidden .metadata folder from your workspace, remove all your projects from your workspace (but of course not from the disk!). 
Restart Flash Builder, open your workspace folder and then reimport them.

If the above does not work, your project might be corrupted.
To fix this, you will have to take a look at your hidden .actionScriptProperties and .project files in your project folder.
Create a new 4.0 project and compare the values of these files to your corrupted project's file. Look especially at the project natures.

If that still doesn't work, remove your workspace, create a new one.
Create a new project and copy all source files of your corrupted project into this project.
Do not copy the .actionScriptProperties and .project files (which is what you get when copying over the whole folder since they are hidden files)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add the run/debug-buttons by editing

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml
```

First close FB and backup the file! 
Then search for `<descriptor>`-Tag with `label="Flash"`.

Paste the inside the `<descriptor>`-Tag, maybe after

```
<alwaysOnActionSet id="org.eclipse.ui.actionSet.openFiles"/>
```

the following line

```
<alwaysOnActionSet id="com.adobe.flexbuilder.standalone.launch"/>
```

Save file and start FB.

Answer (score 0):

We have had this problem as well with **FlashBuilder 4.5**. None of the proposed solution were working. We loose 5 hours to try to solve this, even reinstalling Flash Builder did nothing. That was perfectly strange, as our project perfectly ran on another machine while it was checked out from scratch from same repository on both machines.

Finally got the solution : Go to `Users/<yourPCuserName>/AppData/Roaming/Macromedia/Flash Player/Logs`
edit the **mm.cfg** file (it is the debugging setup file for FlashPlayer...)
there should only have two lines :

```
ErrorReportingEnable=1
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
```

We did have something like this in it, that was completely blocking FlashPlayer in debugging / run an AIR App.

```
SuppressDebuggerExceptionDialogs=1
PreloadSWF=C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\12l6me0w.default\extensions\flashfirebug@o-minds.com\chrome\content\flashfirebug\flashfirebug.swf
```

**flashfirebug** is a Firefox debugger for Flash...

Remove those 2 lines, your apps will start again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case it was the Flash Player (Flash Player Debugger.app on a Mac platform) hanging. Try quitting from the app (if it shows a Force Quit on a Mac it's a good sign) and restarting it.